# is it possible to matching b / w images without feature extraction steps? if possible which algorithm may be more suitable?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, algorithms

these are example of my image

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

i have a 245 images similar to it ,i obtained these b/w images after preprocessing stage , i want to use them for recognition persons(not verification) in matlab. can i performe matching algorithm on these image after division into 2 group(one for training and the second for testing) without implementing feature extraction algorithm such as PCA,ICA,.....?

if it is possible , which are the suitable matching algorithms that are preferable for this purpose , especially i need to use matlab ?

any help please?really i need your opinions and consultations.

thanks in advance

Comment: PCA and ICA are not feature extraction algorithms, they're dimensionality reduction techniques. Feature extraction methods are useful because they make the recognition task much more robust - instead of using the image pixels, you transform/extract the pixels to another (much simpler) feature space.

Comment: thanks for your good illustration.can you give me example on suitable feature extraction algorithm that you prefer for my image?

Comment: What you need to define is - which images you seem close enough which you think should be discarded. So post another image (with some variation which should also pass) and another one which should not be taken up. Also, let us know - the domain. For example are you only restricted to such Black background / white line images? or are these edge detection images? Or you may also want to have general real life images?

Comment: @Dipan.similar and different images to the original one were added.also i am only restricted to images similar to these black background / white line images .thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible!**

For example, you can take pixel by pixel comparison and apply MSE (mean square error). If the error is close to zero, it is the same picture.

However, you will be able to recognize only those images which are picture perfect matching. For example, you won't be able to account for brightness variations, scale variations, minor transformations, compression loss (e.g. JPEG) etc. So while human being might just see them as *SAME* image - they are not on every pixel basis. Depending on how much strict or tolerant your application needs to be, do we really need to then look for advanced algorithms that are smart enough to be invariant to these factors.

---

**EDIT:**

After your clarification, it does sound like you have more of a special case of matching rather than general purpose recognition problem.

Given the following assumptions:

1. A gray scale (or color) images are first converted to binary through some thresholding process.
2. Mostly these images are lines (thick or thin) and the key differentiation is how far these edges are from others.
3. Edges could be of arbitrary shapes and contours -no geometrical assumptions.
4. Given the edge detection limitations (in the presence of noise) and thresholding algorithms, edges might be disjoint

Here is what i would suggest to apply:

1. Edge following algorithms - to make continuous edges where applicable.
   Ref #1. http://www.slideshare.net/kiara1011000/edge-following-algorithm-chiara-galdi
2. Apply Housdourf distances and similar shape/contour matching
   Ref #1. [Haudorff Distance by Normad](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/98/normand/main.html)
   Ref #2. [CV Online: The Hausdorff Distance](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/98/normand/main.html)
   Ref #3. [Hausorff based Matching](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/vision/hausdorff/hausmatch.html)

Basic idea is that if all edges are more or less at the same locations and of same length, then the images are same.

Given that large portion of region which contains Black and implies no information- MSE would be an extremely BAD idea.

I am only giving you some basic direction toward formulating your problem. As you dig deeper  you can put more specific questions. I would be keen to know what works for you finally.

---

**EDIT 2: Adding one specific solution**

One simple possible metric i can think of is:

Say, `Ref[i][j]` is the reference image and `Test[i][j]` is the test image.

```
pixel_similarity = 0; 
For each pixel in Ref[i][j]  
{  
  if ( Ref[i][j] == Edge_pixel )   
     (k,l) <- find_nearest_edge_pixel(Ref, Test, i, j, window_size)  
     pixel_similarity += weighted_similarity (i, j, k, l)   
}  

image_similarity_metric = error / (total_edge_pixels_in_ref);
```

*Please Note that this algorithm will be quite limited for heavy scaling and rotation. This is first step. Notify me for any typo or lack of clarity!*

*Observations:*

1. If you keep two identical images (pixel by pixel)- you will find that (k,l) will be same as (i,j) and weighted error should be = 1.
2. By dividing the number of edge pixels by total edge population, you will get similarity metric = 1.0 for perfectly matching images.
3. When edges are almost similar, but slightly misaligned score will decline gradually. The `weighted_similarity` function should be chosen smartly to deal with what you consider as reasonably aligned edge vs. one that should be discarded.
4. Other extreme is that if total number of edge pixels in Ref is zero - there is no way to compare it with any other one (since we are considering background pixels having no information related to match).

Try to work this out and see what results you get.

Happy to help you!

Comment: thanks in advance Dipan . i need the least error rate and i will try to find the good algorithm.

Comment: @Dipan.i ask God to protect you.i will try to apply your suggestions and inform you about what i can obtain.thankssssss

Comment: .I failed to apply the edge following algorithm . now , it was requested from me to apply reigid registration algorithm on this images to compare my results with another results.so , i need first to try connecting or linking the disconnecting edges , then i try the rigid registration algorithm after that i will ensure that my preprocessing steps is good then i return to apply a dimensionality reduction algorithm with matching algorithm that may be Hausdroff.please help me, i am confounded and i can't start .

Comment: `edge following algorithm` can be added later to improve the results. Can you simply try and compute some distance between images - such as hausdorff or any other distance metric between edge pixels? Select one image and try to plot such metric (error) and see if there is a clear difference in that quantity that distinguish matching vs. non matching images. If there is significant meat in the feature vector (and comparison metric) only then there is a point in optimizing it.

Comment: your comment about the edge following algorithm is very clear and good.

Comment: your comment about the edge following algorithm is very clear and good.but you edition (EDIT 2: Adding one specific solution),is not very clear for example  {  if ( Ref[i][j] == Edge_pixel )   } , here how can i compaire with edge_pixel , where i get it from ?

    { (k,l) <- find_nearest_edge_pixel(Ref, Test, i, j, window_size)  } here according any factor can i select specific window size.}
are there any other clarification for creating  {weighted_error function}  
 i know that i am annoying to you ,i am so sorry but i am new to all fields that i work in it now.

Comment: You aren't annoying! Basically, let's say Ref[5][6] is an edge pixel. Now had this been relatively similar image Test[5][6] should also be an edge pixel. With little distortion, you can say that you *will* find edge pixel (closest to [5][6]) as Test[5+k][6+l]. If k=0 && l=0 i would give the similarity = 1, If k=1, l=1 from a window of say 9x9 i would similarity = 0.9 and if k>9, l>9 i would give similarity = 0; Sorry - the typo is wrong word `weighted_error` it is `pixel_similarity` not error.

Comment: thank you very much. according to what i can say that this is edge pixel when i programming in matlab and the same for weighted -similarity.how can i programme them in matlab.also what are the theoritical name for this method in order to read about it.regards

Comment: I think all your white pixels are edge pixels. weighted similarity is *not* a known terminology. you just define a function on your own. Basically you can have some function over `(i-k, j-l)`. `(0,0)` will have value 1, and will decrease proportionality as `i-k`, or `j-l` increases.

Comment: i tried translation and rotation , but there is unexpected result , so i also asked another question. if you can ,see it and give me your advice please.